# Can't update Eclipse Juno in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, updates, 64-bit, proxy, eclipse

I'm trying to get updates and install new plugin from Eclipse Juno (4.2) on Ubuntu 12.10 (amd/x64).

I've tried every solution posted on this forum for previous versions (changing proxy settings, changing Java/jdk settings, installing gtk, adding '-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true' do /etc/eclipse.ini... etc).

i always get the following:

```
'eclipse.buildId=M20120914-1800
java.version=1.7.0_15
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

Error
Fri Feb 22 15:15:07 BRT 2013
Communication with repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno failed.

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.readSocksReply(SocksSocketImpl.java:126)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:459)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.events.socket.SocketEventCreateUtil.createSocket(SocketEventCreateUtil.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.internal.provider.filetransfer.httpclient.ECFHttpClientProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(ECFHttpClientProtocolSocketFactory.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.internal.provider.filetransfer.httpclient.ECFHttpClientProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(ECFHttpClientProtocolSocketFactory.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.internal.provider.filetransfer.httpclient.ECFHttpClientProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(ECFHttpClientProtocolSocketFactory.java:65)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient.HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.runRequest(HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.AbstractFileSystemBrowser$DirectoryJob.run(AbstractFileSystemBrowser.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Comment: How did you install Eclipse? Through Ubuntu's repository? Then use `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, answer to this question is quite surprising, and I can't explain why the following solution works, but as a matter of fact it does work!

You need to do nothing in the config files, and no command line arguments to the eclipse command either (while starting eclipse).

All that needs to be done is this: set proxy to manual mode, and set only HTTP and HTTPS values for proxy. Make sure you keep the SOCKS proxy empty.

This solved the problem for me!